# split the sentence according to some criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database FSTP. This db include 2 tables. `dbo.CLIENTS` and `dbo.CLIENTS_address`.

I should select column [address] from `dbo.CLIENTS` which looks like:

1. Without phone number:
   010010, c.Paris, Saint-Gilles,  st. Rue, b. 75003, of. 27
2. With phone number:
   516097, Capen-Hall, Buffalo, NY 14260, of. 1611. PHONE: (716) 645-3321

I want to divide this text to columns and write to `dbo.CLIENTS_address`

I write code. It is work good with zip and city.
But I can't divide Address and Phone

```
select
 case when CHARINDEX(' ',CLIENTS.adres)>0 then
     SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres,1,CHARINDEX(' ',CLIENTS.adres)-2) 
 else 
     adres 
 end [ZIP],
 case when CHARINDEX(',',CLIENTS.adres)>0 then 
     SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres,9,CHARINDEX(',',CLIENTS.adres,9)-9) 
 else 
     adres 
 end [city], 
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ',CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN 
 SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres,CHARINDEX(',',CLIENTS.adres,9)+1,len(CLIENTS.adres))               
 ELSE 
    NULL 
 END as [Address],
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Phone',CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN
     SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres,CHARINDEX('Phone. ', CLIENTS.adres)+5,len(CLIENTS.adres)) 
 ELSE 
     NULL 
 END as [Phone]
  from [FSTP].[dbo].[CLIENTS]
```

The result what I expected is:

```
 SELECT * FROM CLIENTS_address;
+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+
| zip   | city      | Address                                 | Phone        |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+
| 010010| Paris     | Saint-Gilles,  st. Rue, b. 75003, of. 27|  NULL        |
| 516097| Capen-Hall| NY 14260, of. 1611.                     |(716) 645-3321|
+-------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+
```

but I get this:

```
 SELECT * FROM CLIENTS_address;
+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+
| zip   | city      | Address                                 | Phone        |
+-------+-----------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+
| 010010| Paris     | Saint-Gilles,  st. Rue, b. 75003, of. 27|  NULL        |
| 516097| Capen-Hall| NY 14260, of. 1611. (716) 645-3321      |(716) 645-3321|
+-------+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQLQuery](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5b3e3/19):

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CLIENTS.adres)-2)
           ELSE adres
       END [ZIP],
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, 9, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)-9)
           ELSE adres
       END [city],
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', CLIENTS.adres)>0
                AND CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)+1, CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres)-CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)-2)
           WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)+1, len(CLIENTS.adres))
           ELSE NULL
       END AS [Address],
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('Phone', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres)+7, len(CLIENTS.adres))
           ELSE NULL
       END AS [Phone]
FROM Table1 CLIENTS
```

Results:

```
|    ZIP |       city |                                  Address |          Phone |
|--------|------------|------------------------------------------|----------------|
| 010010 |    c.Paris |  Saint-Gilles, st. Rue, b. 75003, of. 27 |         (null) |
| 516097 | Capen-Hall |             Buffalo, NY 14260, of. 1611. | (716) 645-3321 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(' ', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN 
    SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', CLIENTS.adres)-2)
ELSE 
    adres
END [ZIP],
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN 
    SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, 9, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)-9)
ELSE 
    adres
END [city],
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', CLIENTS.adres)>0 AND CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres) > 0 THEN 
        SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)+1, CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres)-CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)-1)
    WHEN CHARINDEX(', ', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN 
         SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX(',', CLIENTS.adres, 9)+1, len(CLIENTS.adres))
ELSE 
    NULL
END AS [Address],
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('Phone', CLIENTS.adres)>0 THEN 
    SUBSTRING(CLIENTS.adres, CHARINDEX('Phone: ', CLIENTS.adres)+7, len(CLIENTS.adres))
ELSE
    NULL
END AS [Phone]
FROM Table1 CLIENTS
```

For testing you may try this

```
 declare @mychar nvarchar(max)
 set @mychar = '516097, Capen-Hall, Buffalo, NY 14260, of. 1611. PHONE: (716) 645-3321'
 select SUBSTRING(@mychar,CHARINDEX(',',@mychar,9)+1,len(@mychar))  ---- your query
 select SUBSTRING(@mychar,CHARINDEX(',',@mychar,9)+1,CHARINDEX('PHONE:', @mychar)-CHARINDEX(',',@mychar,9)-1)   --- porposed solution
```

Comment: You are awesome!